# Porcentaje mediante windows functions bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, porcentaje

En mi trabajo me pidieron calcular un porcentaje en tablas de BigQuery, hice el calculo pero quería saber si es posible hacerlo usando Windows Functions. El propósito es saber si es mas eficiente hacerlo de esa forma.

Les paso la consulta que hice (no es exactamente igual, solo quiero aprender el concepto):

```
with

rows_with_state as (
 select
  id,
  date,
  device,
  domain
from table_1
where state = 'state'
)
total_state as (
  select 
    date, 
    count(1) as occurrences
  from rows_with_state
  group by 1
),
total as (
  select 
    date, 
    count(1) as total_rows
  from table_1
  group by 1
)

select
  total_state.date,
  safe_divide(total_state.occurrences, total.total_rows) * 100 as percentage
from total_state
left join total
on total_state.date = total.date
order by 1
```

Me da la sensación que no es muy eficiente hacerlo con sub-queries, por eso pregunto por windows functions o algún otro método mejor.

Cualquier comentario se agradece.

Slds!

Answer (score 0):

#### Hola te dejo esta posible solución haciendo uso de partition by

```
with tabla_1 AS (
                  SELECT 
                  '2023-01-01' AS DATE,
                  'STATE' AS ESTADO

                  UNION ALL

                  SELECT
                  '2023-01-01' AS DATE,
                  'TEST' AS ESTADO

                  UNION ALL

                  SELECT
                  '2023-02-01' AS DATE,
                  'STATE' AS ESTADO

                  UNION ALL

                  SELECT
                  '2023-03-01' AS DATE,
                  'TEST' AS ESTADO
)

SELECT DISTINCT
DATE,
SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO = 'STATE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY DATE), COUNT(ESTADO) OVER(PARTITION BY DATE)) AS percentage

FROM tabla_1

GROUP BY 1, ESTADO
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo esta consulta responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.